# PyDev miss configuration with EClipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have installed java 8 ,Eclipse Kepler and Python34.Now i have installed Pydev through EClipse>>Help>>install new software but it is not showing in File >>New Project or Windows>> Open Perspective. I have installed Pydev many time but it's not showing and i have seen also many of stack over flow but still iy's not working.

Comment: The current pydev requires Eclipse Neon - Kepler is way too old.

Comment: have an other option..????

Comment: How about actually reading the pydev [Install page](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) which tells you what you need for different Eclipse releases. Or actually install a modern Eclipse, Kepler is ancient.

Answer (score 0):

please crosecheck that Eclipse take Java 8 version only .because pydev needs Java 8 version. Even if you installed java 8 in your system. But check that the Eclipse took Java 8 version nothing else.If not then uninstall the eclipse and again install it so that it will take system java 8 version.

After this if still issue persist, then try with Eclipse Luna. I am facing the same issues.Now it is working for me.